# Web api Bulk data (million) import using Batching

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to import thousands of json data (posted from UI) .From ui that will be posted in form json to webapi.

I am thinking to following below mentioned steps for Technicle design

1.Save json data to in file (.json) on server location and make entry json file path in database table with New status.

2.I will develop Window service as an background service which will pick up json file,validate json data and import it in database table .While processing ,status will be InProcess. While processing of data , I will create batch of 1000 records using Parallel Task library

3.After Successfull Processing Status will be in Complete status

Is This best way of processing data?

Is it possible to validate json with some schema ? How?

What things I need to take care while processing ,validating json in terom of size,special charter etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my opinions about your questions:

- It's a good choice to do the batch processing in the background if it's a big file, because you will not block the user UI while processing the data.
- You can do the processing like you said using a Windows Service. However, I suggest you to check [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). It think that it could be a good choice for your scenario, but you have to see it and decide.
- Take care using PTL (Parallel Task Library). If you don't have good practices you can get a worse result that using a single process. Check this [suggested link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Check this another [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) regarding Json schema validation.
- Last but not least, evaluate if it would be nice to notify your user when the process is finished. Maybe a notification in the UI or an email.